# how to find out whether all array elements match some condition?

Tags: ruby

I have a big array and I need to know whether all its elements are divisible by 2.

I'm doing it this way, but it's sort of ugly:

```
_true = true
arr.each { |e| (e % 2).zero? || _true = false }
if _true == true
    # ...
end
```

How to do this without extra loops/assignments?

Comment: Why do you do `% 4` when you want to see if they are divisible by two?

Comment: just a typo. your `&:even?` stuff looks neat but yet too hacky for me :) thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ruby's got you covered.

```
if arr.all? {|e| (e % 2).zero?}
```

There's also `any?` if you need to check whether at least one element has a given property.

Answer (score 23):

This will do.

```
arr.all?(&:even?)
```